# Clarification in PyTorch's autograd with respect to tracking weights

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I was reading this [blog from PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/introyt/autogradyt_tutorial.html). Just before the **AutoGrad in training** Section , it is mentioned

> Be aware that only leaf nodes of the computation have their gradients computed. If you tried, for example, print(c.grad) you’d get back None. In this simple example, only the input is a leaf node, so only it has gradients computed.

Then weights are also considered to be leaf nodes. In the subsequent **AutoGrad in training** Section this below code block is executed.

```
BATCH_SIZE = 16
DIM_IN = 1000
HIDDEN_SIZE = 100
DIM_OUT = 10

class TinyModel(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TinyModel, self).__init__()

        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Linear(1000, 100)
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Linear(100, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        return x

some_input = torch.randn(BATCH_SIZE, DIM_IN, requires_grad=False)
ideal_output = torch.randn(BATCH_SIZE, DIM_OUT, requires_grad=False)

model = TinyModel()
```

When

```
print(model.layer2.weight.grad)
```

is executed it is shown as `None`.

But after training with the below code snippet, the weights have gradients,

```
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

prediction = model(some_input)

loss = (ideal_output - prediction).pow(2).sum()

loss.backward()

print(model.layer2.weight.grad[0][0:10])
```

So is my understanding correct? i.e when weights are initialised by calling `TinyModel()`, the `requires_autograd` is set to False. Only when the training starts happening with `loss.backward()` then the `requires_autograd` is set to True and the gradient is kept track?

But in other examples, when we create PyTorch models from scratch, where we initialise the weights randomly along with `requires_grad=True`, the gradient is tracked from beginning.

Or is the gradient tracking generally enabled only when it is started to be trained? If so why initially it was returning `None` in the above example.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by `requires_autograd` you mean `requires_grad`.

> when weights are initialised by calling TinyModel(), the requires_autograd is set to False.

No, this isn't true. The attribute `model.layer2.weight` is an instance of `nn.Parameter` which has `requires_grad == True` by default. You can verify this yourself:

```py
model = TinyModel()
assert isinstance(model.layer2.weight, nn.Parameter)
assert model.layer2.weight.requires_grad
assert all(p.requires_grad for p in model.parameters())
```

> why initially it was returning None in the above example

The value of `model.layer2.weight.grad` is `None` because at that point no gradient is computed yet. In fact, no forward computation is even computed yet. When `loss.backward()` is executed, the autograd engine computes the gradient of all tensor `p` with `p.requires_grad == True` and stores this gradient in `p.grad`. That's why `model.layer2.weight.grad` is no longer `None` after `loss.backward()`.

Comment: Just to clarify, so initially p.grad (for any trainable tensor p) is None and not zero ?

Comment: @MuhammadWaseem that’s right